# Fastest way to use reflection for converting datareader to list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using reflection to convert datareader into the generic collection list. Can anybody
suggest me the best way to implement reflection for this? I want the fastestway?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic collection list"? What's wrong with using a `DataTable`?

Comment: Should use linq expressions instead of reflection. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841120/generic-dbdatareader-to-listt-mapping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is something like:

```
List<MyClass> list = LoadFromDataReader<MyClass>(dataReader);
```

with:

```
class MyClass
{
    [DataField("FirstName")] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataField("LastName")] public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I do this by:

1. Using `Type.GetProperties` and `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute` to put together a dictionary mapping field names to `PropertyInfo` objects
2. Calling `PropertyInfo.SetValue` on each field in each record

You can cache the results of step (1), since the field/property mapping isn't going to change during the life of the application.

If performance is a problem (i.e. if step (2) turns out to be a bottleneck), then you have to avoid using reflection and generate code to set the properties directly. A couple of alternative improvements:

- Use `System.CodeDom` to generate a C# class containing code to set the properties according to the respective fields on the `IDataReader`. Note that `System.CodeDom` invokes the `csc.exe` compiler in the background, so you need to generate this code once at startup and re-use it on each call.
- Use `System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod` to generate IL code that sets properties. Less runtime overhead than `System.CodeDom`, but since you're generating raw IL, this is much harder to write and debug. Use as a last option.

Comment: You can use Lambda expression as an alternative to reflection emit.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on exactly what you are looking at doing.  I implement a object/interface process where I create information objects that hold the data that is returned.  I then use an interface `IFillable` or something similar that passes a DR to the object and the object does the hydration from the DR.

This way I avoid the need for reflection, and the performance is great.  I then have a few generic helper methods for `Fill` and `FillCollection`.

I got the idea based on stuff inside the CBO object of the [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) framework.  It also implements a reflection method as well, that is fairly decent in performance.