# How to map a DataReader to class properties and maintain performance?

Tags: c#, reflection, datareader

Preamble:

1. All data connection strings,
   connections, etc are created using
   DbProviderFactories.
2. Code is mixed C# and VB.Net from
   mulitple libraries.

I am mapping a DbDataReader to entities and have some benchmarks:

```
[0] retrieved 159180 records in 45135 ms
[1] retrieved 159180 records in 45008 ms
[2] retrieved 159180 records in 44814 ms
[3] retrieved 159180 records in 44987 ms
[4] retrieved 159180 records in 44914 ms
[5] retrieved 159180 records in 45224 ms
[6] retrieved 159180 records in 45829 ms
[7] retrieved 159180 records in 60762 ms
[8] retrieved 159180 records in 52128 ms
[9] retrieved 159180 records in 47982 ms
```

This is a significant amount of time and extremely poor considering it only takes 17 seconds to query from Sql Server Management Studio. My select statement:

"SELECT * FROM tbl_MyTable"

Table contains 43 fields and probably isn't indexed as best as it should; however, performing a *select all*, I wouldn't expect indexing to be problematic. So ... here is what I am doing:

**Define an entity:**

```
public class Concept
{
    #region Columns
    [DataParameter("ConceptID", DbType.Int32)]
    public Int32 ConceptID
    { get; set; }
    [DataParameter("ConceptName", DbType.String)]
    public string ConceptName
    { get; set; }
    [DataParameter("ConceptTypeID", DbType.Int32)]
    public Int32 ConceptTypeID
    { get; set; }
    [DataParameter("ActiveYN", DbType.Boolean)]
    public bool ActiveYN
    { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

**Query DataReader:**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
{
    sw.Start();
    var results = session.QueryReader<Concept>(
        new SqlCommand(command), dr => new Concept());

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] retrieved {1} records in {2} ms", i, results.Count(), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset();
}
```

... calling:

```
Public Function QueryReader(Of TEntity As {Class, New})(ByVal Command As DbCommand, _
                                                        ByVal Projection As Func(Of DbDataReader, TEntity)) _
                                                        As IEnumerable(Of TEntity)

    Dim list As IEnumerable(Of TEntity)

    Command.Connection = dataReader.NewConnection
    Command.Connection.Open()

    Using _reader As DbDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        list = _reader.Query(Of TEntity)(Projection).ToList()
    End Using

    Command.Connection.Close()

    Return list
End Function
```

... and extension method `QueryReader<T>`: *edit placement of new TEntity() - thanks @Henk*

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>(this DbDataReader Reader,
    Func<DbDataReader, TEntity> Projection)
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    //   moving this reflection to another class
    Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> props;

    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        TEntity entity = new TEntity();

        if (!entities.TryGetValue(typeof(TEntity).ToString(), out props))
        {
            //  reflection over TEntity
            props = (from p in entity.GetType().GetProperties()
                     from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataParameterAttribute), false)
                     select p)
                     .ToDictionary(p => p.Name);

            entities.Add(typeof(TEntity).ToString(), props);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PropertyInfo> field in props)
        {
            if (null != Reader[field.Key] && Reader[field.Key] != DBNull.Value)
            { field.Value.SetValue(entity, Reader[field.Key], null); }
        }

        yield return entity;
    }
}
```

***Any suggestions on increasing performance would be greatly appreciated ...***

---

### Update

I implemented dapper-dot-net as @EtienneT suggested - here are the retrieval times:

```
[0] retrieved 159180 records in 6874 ms
[1] retrieved 159180 records in 6866 ms
[2] retrieved 159180 records in 6570 ms
[3] retrieved 159180 records in 6785 ms
[4] retrieved 159180 records in 6693 ms
[5] retrieved 159180 records in 6735 ms
[6] retrieved 159180 records in 6627 ms
[7] retrieved 159180 records in 6739 ms
[8] retrieved 159180 records in 6569 ms
[9] retrieved 159180 records in 6666 ms
```

Comment: 160K records with 43 fields populating entities via reflection? I'd say 45-50 seconds is pretty decent, but maybe I'm too forgiving.

Comment: @Anthony: I think it's *decent* ... but I want **wow** - especially since I use a dictionary to map the reader[field] to the propertyInfo ... but maybe my expectations are too high. ;)

Comment: Just for fun, try writing an old-fashioned `while(Reader.Read())` loop, Fx 2.0 style. It should give you an idea how expensive all this reflection and indirection is.

Comment: And I'm perplexed the `new TEntity()` is outside the while. After this is done, are all your records the same?

Comment: @Henk: Fx 2.0 style ??? I was thinking about trying to push into an anonymous type instead of a class; but having an IEnumerable<TConcrete> is soooo much better than working with anonTypes or DataTables. Plus my TConcrete objects are quite mutable and I plan on using them with a similar implementation with a DataReader to write back to the data store ... if all that makes sense.  ;)

Comment: @Henk: yup - I had been messing with it ... thanks

Comment: @Anthony: now I have my **wow** I was looking for. It's faster than MS Sql Mgr Studio.

Comment: Mixing your drinks? (c# and vb)

Comment: @AranMulholland: unfortunately, yes :) at the time I had a DAL written in VB by another developer and I was building the backend in C#. The beauty of .Net!

Comment: Few things. 1) You're passing parameter "Projection" to your Query method. Then why not just return the projected form in place of all this reflection? Or was it a mistake? 2) Your strategy to not assign anything to property when the db value is DBNull can backfire. For e.g. assume your default constructor of entity looks like this: "public T() { P = someValue; }" .Now if property "P" is DbNull in db and you are not assigning anything to it in your mapping code, then the mapper returns a T where P = someValue (assigned in constructor) while in db it is DBNull. These are rarities but still..

Comment: Also you're reading multiple times from reader for a single value. I think this can be greatly improved. See:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58251/transform-datareader-to-listt-using-reflections. Ultimately I believe one should use expression trees here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812034/fastest-way-to-use-reflection-for-converting-datareader-to-list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841120/generic-dbdatareader-to-listt-mapping, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105549/c-sharp-idatareader-to-object-mapping-using-generics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered a micro ORM like dapper.net?

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

It is made by the developers of StackOverflow and map an SQL query directly to your objects. It generates and caches IL code to map the SQL results to your objects.  So the IL code is generated only one time per type.  Never used this, but if you need performance to map your SQL results to .net objects, it is the library you need.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that existed. Looks nifty

Comment: I'm looking at it now - I can give it a pretty quick test I think - I'll post some benchmarks as soon as I have it completed.

Comment: Something similar made by Rob Conery: http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive

Also pretty fast, but it deals more with dynamic objects.  Dapper is still faster from what I read.

Comment: Only negative thing I saw about Dapper is that it generates IL to map your objects and then cache it.  So if there's a bug in the generated IL, good luck.  Look at the dapper code: https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L677

Comment: So far, it seems to be quite fast and without issue. I don't expect much in the way of IL bugs being that Marc Gravell is involved.

Comment: @IAbstract `Dapper` GitHub page says: Hand coded using `SqlDataReader` has 2 ms more performance than `Dapper` , so its better to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464929/2218697) extension method or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525024/2218697) to map to class.